# show data if not listed in another table

Tags: php, sql

I am wondering how to check if data exists in another table.

Basically I have 2 tables. 1 = `networks` and 2 = `usernetworks`

```
$networks = $this->db->query("SELECT companyname,description,commision FROM (`networks`)");
```

In my table `usernetworks` it has a column `userID` and `networkid`

I want to check if the id from `networks` and the userid = '9' is listed in the usernetworks table.

Basically I want to display the networks that the user is not already a member of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select n.*
from networks n
where not exists (select 1
                  from usernetworks un
                  where un.networkid = n.networkid and un.userid = 9
                 );
```